# Regex is capturing too many characters

Tags: regex

I have a regex where I'm trying to get the first number (over 3 chars long) inside square brackets. But the regex seems to capture the square brackets. As far as I can see, captures are done with round brackets. So how come the capture includes "[12345]"??

To be clear, I only want the number 12345

```
var pattern = @"^\s{0,2}\[([0-9]{3,})\]";
```

So this is:
possible spaces 2 chars
square bracket opener escaped
open capture bracket
number range 0 through 9 (3 or more chars)
close capture bracket
square close bracket escaped

Example
Text: [2090] fdksljkl fdsa
The captured value: [2090]

Why not 2090? How can I capture only 2090?

The capture brackets are clearly only around the number range 0-9. Why does it pick up square brackets? The universe no longer makes sense [to me :) ]

Sorry if this type of question has been done to death - I tried searching a lot, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first captured group (usually #0) will be the entire string. Look out for that :)

Comment: Your value is in the first capturing group https://regex101.com/r/OgcBsH/1 (highlighted in green)

Comment: Thanks for your help. That was a very clear example the fourth bird

Comment: `Regex.Match(string, pattern)?.Groups[1].Value` is all you need. There is no problem with your regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you solution was working, you just need to capture the result of group 1 instead of group 0, as you can see on these ruby example:

```rb
irb(main):008:0> /^\s{0,2}\[([0-9]{3,})\]/.match('[2090] fdksljkl fdsa')
=> #<MatchData "[2090]" 1:"2090">
irb(main):009:0> result[0]
=> "[2090]"
irb(main):010:0> result[1]
=> "2090"
```

But if your language not support to do that, or you need to return in a single line:

```
irb(main):013:0> result = /(?<=\[)([0-9]{3,})(?=\])/.match('[2090] fdksljkl fdsa')
=> #<MatchData "2090" 1:"2090">
irb(main):014:0> result[0]
=> "2090"
```

(?<=[) - positive lookbehind for [

([0-9]{3,}) - your regex

(?=]) - positive lookahead for ]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, the universe makes sense again :)